# n^(1/n) growth rate compare to n^a

Tags: time-complexity

I have a function **n<sup>a</sup>**, where `0 < a < 1` and **n<sup>1/n</sup>**. Which of these grow faster? They are both **n<sup>a fraction</sup>** so technically at some instance `a = 1/n` So how do I rank this? If `a < 1/n` or `a > 1/n` then it's obvious, but all I have for `a` is that it's *between* 0 and 1 exclusive. So how do I know which has the greater growth rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **O(n<sup>1/n</sup>) is in fact O(1).**

> log(n<sup>1/n</sup>) = 1/n*log(n) = log(n)/n

and it is approximately zero(because `n` is much more than `log(n)`)  so :

> log(n<sup>1/n</sup>) = 0 ==> O(n<sup>1/n</sup>) = O(1)

2. **O(n<sup>a</sup>) > O(1). when a>0**

so you have **O(n<sup>1/n</sup>) < O(n<sup>a</sup>)**

In simple words, whatever `a` is even if `a` is so little for one `k` we have that for every `n>k` `a>1/n` and that what is behind my answer.
(Suppose `a` a little number you just need to consider `n`s that are greater than `1/a` and for them a>1/n).